# Why can I not get number of rows in my Google fusion table?

Tags: javascript, json, google-fusion-tables

I (newcomer to javascript etc) have fabricated the following webpage to get the number of rows in my Google fusion table. My div to receive the result however shows "0" indicating an error. Any suggestions? (I am also not sure about which links I have to add in the

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>test count</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function dataHandler(resp) 
{
  try
  {$('#result').html((resp.table.rows[1][1]));}
  catch(err)
  {$('#result').html('0');}
};

function getData() 
{
  var tableId = '1G2iUAdGUAcEGCTfDykKnURZvY1QFe6pxoBKqi8A4';
  var queryUrlHead = 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=';
  var queryUrlTail = '&jsonCallback=getData';
  var query = "SELECT COUNT() FROM " + tableId ;
  window.alert(queryUrlHead + query + queryUrlTail);
  var queryurl = encodeURI(queryUrlHead + query + queryUrlTail);
  var jqxhr = $.get(queryurl, dataHandler, "jsonp");
};

function initialize() 
{
  getData();
  dataHandler();
};

</script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="result">xx</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your alert shows the correct value?

Comment: alert shows: "h t t p://w w w.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=SELECT COUNT() FROM 1G2iUAdGUAcEGCTfDykKnURZvY1QFe6pxoBKqi8A4&jsonCallback=getData", which I assume to be correct (spaces added in h t t p to allow showing text here)

Comment: Put an alert to show response.

Comment: function dataHandler(resp) 
{
  window.alert(resp);
  try
  {$('#result').html((resp.table.rows[1][1]));}
  catch(err)
  {$('#result').html('0');}
};   yields "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the URL of the API is not correct, it should be

   ```
   https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query
   ```
2. FusionTable-Queries require at least a valid key
3. the desired information will be accessible via `resp.rows[0][0]`
4. remove the call of `dataHandler();` in initialize()

Fixed script(insert your own valid key):

```
function dataHandler(resp) 
{  
  try
  {$('#result').html((resp.rows[0][0]));}
  catch(err)
  {$('#result').html('0');}
};

function getData() 
{ var yourApiKey='insert your key here';
  var tableId = '1G2iUAdGUAcEGCTfDykKnURZvY1QFe6pxoBKqi8A4';
  var queryUrlHead = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=';
  var queryUrlTail = '&jsonCallback=getData&key='+yourApiKey;
  var query = encodeURIComponent("SELECT COUNT() FROM " + tableId) ;
  var queryurl = queryUrlHead + query + queryUrlTail;
  var jqxhr = $.get(queryurl, dataHandler, "jsonp");
};

function initialize() 
{
  getData();

};
```